# Unity: camera falls through terrain

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, terrain

Problem is:

I have created terrain and I need to fly over terrain with Camera. I added to Camera "Mouse Look" script, RigidBody: usegravity - unchecked and I have added my code in Update method:

```
    float vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (vert != 0)
    {
        if (!Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward, 5))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * flySpeed * vert);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * flySpeed * vert);
        }
    }

    if (hor != 0)
    {   

        if (!Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward, 5))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * flySpeed * hor);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * flySpeed* hor);
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * flySpeed);            
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        Vector3 v = Vector3.down * flySpeed;

        if (!Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward, 5))
        {
            transform.Translate(v);
        }           
    }
```

But sometimes then i go down - Q - camera goes through terrain. Why? 
Also looks ugly if you are moving with camera forward as low as possible over terrain and camera does not fall through it - it starts to jump. Also why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a [Terrain Collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TerrainCollider.html) on your terrain.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to S.Richmonds answer, you can add a character controller or other similar collider-component object to your camera.

See this answer in the unity questions network:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/45763/getting-camera-to-not-see-under-the-ground.html

Answer (score 0):

The Update() method in a monobehavior gets called once each fram. Because the rate which update is called is dependent on frame rate, moving an object by a constant value in Update() can result in inconsistant motion. This can be corrected by multiplying a constant speed by Time.deltaTime, which is the time in seconds since the last frame was rendered. This will fix the fallthrough unless flySpeed is set too high (where the change in position each frame is greater than the collider's size). Additionally as suggested above, using a CharacterController without a rigidbody would be better suited to this situation. Rigidbodies are for objects primarily controlled by physics, while the CharacterController is for objects controlled by scripts.